# Index page retrieve variable from all posts

Tags: javascript, jekyll, github-pages

I have a Jekyll based blog that has some location data in the frontmatter of each post.

For example:

```
mapping:
  locations:
    - title: Times Square
      latitude: 40.758885
      longitude: -73.985134
    - title: Central Park
      latitude: 40.782841
      longitude: -73.965350
```

I would like to retrieve all the locations in all of my posts so I can plot them on a map. Currently I display all locations on a map for a single post at the top of that post by passing the values into a javascript function I have modified from the plugin functionality [here](https://github.com/matthewowen/jekyll-mapping).

For example:
`function () { jekyllMapping.loadScript( {{ page.mapping | jsonify }} ) };`

I am having trouble retrieving all the locations from all the posts to pass to the same function as json.

I have tried:

```
{% capture travel_locations %}
{% for post in site.categories.travel %}
{% for location in post.mapping.locations %}
{{ location | jsonify }}{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}{% endfor %}
{% unless forloop.last %},{% endunless %}{% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
```

%Capture% appears to return as a string not an array element object so I'm forced to jsonify the output inside the loop. The final output is close but gives me no root json element and is not an array so I cannot iterate on it in the javascript. I can concatenate like this `"{\"locations\":[" + {{ travel_locations }} + "]}"` but it of course just gets treated as a big escaped string and not a json object.

I've also tried splitting the capture result back into an array but still no luck.
`{% assign my_locations =  "{{ travel_locations | split:',' | jsonify }} %}`

I hope I'm missing something really simple for retrieving variable values from all posts in a category?

Also, I host the blog as a static site on github pages so plugins are out of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `assign`

Create an empty array

```
{% assign locations = "" | split: "" %}
```

Then fill it with your locations

```
{% for post in site.categories.travel %}
  {% for location in post.mapping.locations %}
    {% assign locations = locations | push: location %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You now have an array with all your locations, ready be jsonified.

**Edit** : 
This code will run on current Github pages' Jekyll version : 2.4.0

In order to work in sync with Github Pages' jekyll version, you need to create a Gemfile containing

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages'
```

Then you do :

```
gem bundler install
bundle install
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

Bing ! http://0.0.0.0:4000/ is the place where everything is ok !

Comment: Ah, it looks like I was over complicating it and getting confused by using capture. I just tried your answer however it results in an empty array?

{% assign locations = "" | split:"" %}
{% for post in site.categories.travel %}
 {% for location in post.mapping.locations %}
  {% assign locations = locations | push: location %}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

Comment: It works here. Maybe you have a variable name problem.

Comment: Is that definitely the syntax for handling arrays? If I add a counter to my inside look it looks to be looping the correct amount of times: 
{% assign counter=0 %}
{% for post in site.categories.travel %}
 {% for location in post.mapping.locations %}
  {% assign counter=counter | plus:1 %} 
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
console.log({{ counter }});

Comment: However even if I just push a static string into the array instead of objects I still have an empty or undefined array:
{% assign locations = "" | split: "" %}
{% for post in site.categories.travel %}
 {% for location in post.mapping.locations %}
  {% assign locations = locations | push:"Daniel" %}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
 console.log({{ locations }});

For this reason I'm not sure it is the variable name?

Comment: Try `console.log("{{ locations }}");`

Comment: No luck, it still shows as empty and becomes `console.log( "" );` in page source

Comment: So, let's start with your pc conf : os, ruby and jekyll versions ?

Comment: OS: OSX 10.10.3
Ruby: 2.0.0p353
Jekyll: 2.2.0

Comment: Yop! Jekyll version is to old. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Wow that was it, thanks! I already had a Gemfile but my github-pages version of jekyll was out of date. Worked as soon as I upgraded. Thanks very much for your persistence. Was this array handling added after 2.2.0?

Comment: array filters like push where added for 2.4.0 release https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/releases/tag/v2.4.0